# What is an alternative to using `__getattr__()` method for wrapper classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, attributes, dynamic-programming

Suppose that I have two classes:

> 1. a class named `Swimmer`
> 2. a class named `Person`

For my particular application, we can ***NOT*** have `Swimmer` inherit from `Person`, although we want something like inheritance.

Instead of class inheritance each `Swimmer` will have an instance of the `Person` class as a member variable.

```python
class Person:
   pass

class Swimmer:

    def __init__(self, person):  
        self._person = person 

    def __getattr__(self, attrname:str):
        try:
            attr = getattr(self._person)
            return attr  
        except AttributeError:
            raise AttributeError
```

---

Perhaps the `Person` class has the following class methods:

> - `kneel()`
> - `crawl()`
> - `walk()`
> - `lean_over()`
> - `lay_down()`

---

The `Swimmer` class has all of the same methods as the `Person` class, plus some additional methods:

> - `run()`
> - `swim()`
> - `dive()`
> - `throw_ball()`

When it comes to kneeling, crawling, walking, and laying down, a `Swimmer` is meant to be a transparent wrapper around the `Person` class.

---

I want to write something like this:

```python
swimmer_instance = SwimmerClass(person_instance)
```

I wrote a `__getattr__()` method.

However, I ran into many headaches with `__getattr__()`.

Consider writing the code `self.oops`. There is no attribute of the `_Swimmer` class named `oops`. We should not look for  `oops` inside of `self._person`.

Aanytime that I mistyped the name of an attribute of `Swimmer`, my computer searched for that attribute in the instance of the `Person` class. Normally, fixing such spelling mistakes is easy. But, with a `__getattr__()` method, tracking down the problem becomes difficult.

How can I avoid this problem?

---

Perhaps one option is create a sub-class of the `Swimmer` class. In the sub-class have have a method, the name of which is a misspelling of `__getattr__`. However, I am not sure about this idea; please advise me.

```python
class _Swimmer:

    def __init__(self, person):  
        self._person = person 

    def run(self):
        return "I ran"

    def swim(self):
        return "I swam"

    def dive(self):
        # SHOULD NOT LOOK FOR `oops` inside of self._person!
        self.oops   
        return "I dove"

    def _getattrimp(self, attrname:str):
        # MISSPELLING OF `__getattr__`
        try:
            attr = getattr(self._person)
            return attr  
        except AttributeError:
            raise AttributeError  

class Swimmer(_Swimmer):
    def __getattr__(self, attrname:str):
        attr = self._getattrimp(attrname)
        return attr
```

Really, it is important to me that we ***not*** look inside of `self._person` for anything except the following:

> - `Kneel()`
> - `Crawl()`
> - `Walk()`
> - `Lean()`
> - `LayDown()`

The solution must be more general than just something what works for the `Swimmer` class and `Person` class.

> ### How do we write a function which accepts any class as input and pops out a class which has methods of the same name as the input class?

We can get a list of `Person` attributes by writing `person_attributes = dir(Person)`.

Is it appropriate to dynamically create a sub-class of `Swimmer` which takes `Person` as input?

```python
class Person:  
    def kneel(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return "I KNEELED"

    def crawl(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return "I crawled"

    def walk(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return "I WALKED"

    def lean_over(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return "I leaned over"

################################################################

import functools

class TransparentMethod:
    def __init__(self, mthd):  
        self._mthd = mthd 

    @classmethod
    def make_transparent_method(cls, old_method):
        new_method = cls(old_method)
        new_method = functools.wraps(old_method)
        return new_method  

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ret_val = self._mthd(*args, **kwargs)   
        return ret_val  

###############################################################

attributes = dict.fromkeys(dir(Person))

for attr_name in attributes.keys():
    old_attr = getattr(Person, attr_name)
    new_attr = TransparentMethod.make_transparent_method(old_attr)

name       = "_Swimmer"
bases      = (object, )

_Swimmer = type(name, bases, attributes) 
  
class Swimmer(_Swimmer):
    pass
```

Comment: "However, I ran into many headaches with `__getattr__()`." Aside from the one described, what else? Also - if the goal is simply to ensure that only specific attributes will be looked for within the wrapped instance, why not just whitelist them in the `__getattr__` logic? Or is the problem that `__getattr__` is called in the first place? If so, **why is that a problem**? Because the exception message refers to `Person` rather than `Swimmer`? Well then - since you are already explicitly handling the exception, why not adapt it rather than re-raising it unmodified?

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon Does my answer below solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a function that will combine two classes into one.

The way I did this was to create a blank container class with the 3 parameter [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) constructor, then loop over every class passed to the function, using `setattr` to set new attributes of the container class. I had to blacklist the `__class__` and `__dict__` attributes because Python doesn't allow one to change these. Note that this function will overwrite previously added methods, such as the `__init__()` method, so pass the class with the constructor last.

I implemented this in the `combineClasses` function below. I also provided an example. In the example, I created the a basic `Person` class and a `_Swimmer` class. I called `combineClasses` on these two and stored the resulting class as `Swimmer`, so it can nicely be called as a wrapper class.

```
def combineClasses(name, *args):
    container = type(name, (object,), {})

    reserved = ['__class__', '__dict__']
    for arg in args:
        for method in dir(arg):
            if method not in reserved:
                setattr(container, method, getattr(arg, method))
    return container


class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def sayHi(self):
        print(f'Hi, I am {self.name}')


class _Swimmer:
    def swim(self):
        print('I am swimming')


class _Cashier:
    def work(self):
        print(f'I am working! My name is {self.name}')


Swimmer = combineClasses('Swimmer', _Swimmer, Person)

bob = Swimmer('Bob')
bob.swim()  # => "I am swimming"
bob.sayHi()  # => "Hi, I am Bob"
print(bob.name)  # => "Bob"
print(type(bob))  # => "<class '__main__.Swimmer'>"
```

Comment: I am really happy that there is only one method present in the `Swimmer` class which is not present in the class named `Person`. My original example was needlessly complicated. I described a class named `Swimmer` which had at least 3 or 4 methods which were not present in the `Person` class. It is sufficient to have only one new method named `swim()`

Comment: in your code you created a default value for the names of new classes. If, by default, you name every new class "container" then there is a high probability that two distinct classes will be created which are both named "container". It is inadvisable to have different classes of same name. I hope that you will edit your answer so as to delete the default value for the name of the new class. New classes should not ever have a default name. The name of the new class should be somthing sensible.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon Thanks for the feedback! I've edited my answer to make the `name` parameter to be the first required positional parameter. I've also changed my code to use the 3 parameter [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) constructor, which dynamically creates a new class with the passed name, which is a better way than changing the `__name__` property.

Comment: Thank you for using the 3 parameter `type()` constructor and not using default arguments (`name = "container"`) for new classes.

Comment: I will note that when we write, `for method in dir(arg)` we  not every element of the directory of `arg` is a method. `arg` is `method` if and only if `arg` is callable. For example, if a class named `Rectangle` has float attributes named `length` and `width`, then `length` and `width` are not class methods. That's probably okay, but I do worry about the difference between member variables (integers, strings, etc..) and methods (callable functions)

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon If only the class methods are copied into the new class, then any fields those methods need won't be present. I'm a bit confused about your concern. What exactly is wrong with the answer?